# cannot enable jboss jmx

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, infinispan

I have an infinispan 8.2 server running, which I need to enable the jmx for.

I followed the server guide and the final `domain.xml` file is :

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
        <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/>
        <expose-resolved-model/>
        <expose-expression-model/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:3.0">
        <!--<endpoint/>-->
        <!--<http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>-->
        <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                <authorization>
                    <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-domain>
            <security-domain name="jaspitest" cache-type="default">
                <authentication-jaspi>
                    <login-module-stack name="dummy">
                        <login-module code="Dummy" flag="optional"/>
                    </login-module-stack>
                    <auth-module code="Dummy"/>
                </authentication-jaspi>
            </security-domain>
        </security-domains>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security-manager:1.0">
        <deployment-permissions>
            <maximum-set>
                <permission class="java.security.AllPermission"/>
            </maximum-set>
        </deployment-permissions>
    </subsystem>
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:3.0">
        <core-environment>
            <process-id>
                <uuid/>
            </process-id>
        </core-environment>
        <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
    </subsystem>
</profile> </profiles>
```

I still cannot connect to the jmx port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that the server is wrapping JMX through remoting (aka JSR 160) so that it uses manager security credentials. So, you either connect locally through jvmstat (VisualVM can do this) or add the bin/client/jboss-client.jar to your client's classpath and use the following service URL to connect: service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://host:9990 (replace http with https if you have enabled TLS on the management interface)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a great help. I managed to connect from the same box on my ethernet, but remote connections still fail. I made sure the jboss.bind.address the public ip, and I can reach it remotely. I can even telnet to the port jmx supposedly listening. But connection using the jconsole with class path fixed, still fails

Answer (score 0):

Since you have this entry:

```
 <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/>
```

the port switches from the management-http port (9990 by default) to the http port (8080 by default), so your connection string needs to switch to:

service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://host:8080